# Running python script from SAS Enterprise Guide

Tags: python, sas

I need some help running a python script from inside SAS. I want to take advantage of the possibility of scheduling a SAS code to run every day, I already have a script in python that manipulates everything I need to do. Is there a way to host the python script into SAS and make it run every day without the need of my pc to be turned on?

Comment: You might be able to use the [CALL SYSTEM](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/69955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1x419xlskdkk0n1tu49vywgnsc7.htm) command to invoke python on the command line

Comment: Are you using EG to connect to SAS running on your PC? Or to a server running somewhere else?  It the later then make sure that your python script can run on that server.

Comment: Are you using SASpy? If so, there are many ways. If not, you need to find out if you have the SAS XCMD enabled and then use that.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to verify if you have the XCMD option enabled. If it's enabled, your log will show XCMD and then you can use an X statement to run your python scripts.

   ```
   proc options option=xcmd;
   run;
   ```
2. Next, find the command line that you'll need to run the scripts from the command line. Then place that after an X in your code or use CALL SYSTEM() or X to execute the command. Hardest part is usually making sure the quotes are correctly resolved.

   ```
   x 'command line command goes here';
   ```